# Writing in multiple languages in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am using the Google Input tool on [this website](https://www.easynepalityping.com/type-urdu) to transliterate English to Urdu language. For example, I write:

[image]

But when I copy and paste it in Rmarkdown, I get this:

[image]

**How can I make Rmarkdown keep the correct sequence of English and Urdu words in the sentence?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some text to be rendered in RTL direction in a R Markdown file following [Pandoc's documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables)

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

::: {dir="rtl"}
ٹھیس اس ا variable
:::
```

It won't show as RTL in the source editor because I don't think [RStudio IDE supports it yet](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3808). By default, it shows text in LTR direction. Other editor too, like Notepad++, but in this one you have a switch to pass to RTL mode using CTRl + ALT + R).

However, in the output, it will be rendered correctly in the resulting HTML file
[image]

With the new Visual Editor in RStudio 1.4 ([still in Preview](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/09/30/rstudio-v1-4-preview-visual-markdown-editing/)), this can change as you can create those div blocks visually and have the text written RTL in visual mode
[image]